# Post comments in Django Homepage

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

i have this code with me as part of a tutorial i was following for blog post. I have a comment section on my detailview, I want it to be shown in the homepage as well. I tried with some codes, but the problem is same comments are showing in all posts (only) in homepage.

please take a look at the code.

I have a comment snippet which I use it in my homepage.

```
<!-- Comment showing section -->
<div class="main-comment-section">
    <div class="container-fluid mt-2">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <!-- Comment Form -->
            <form class="comment-form" method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="content" cols="60" rows="2" maxlength="1000" required="" id="id_content"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn-sm btn-outline-light" style="color: black;">Comment</button>
            </form>
            <!-- Comment Form end -->
        </div>
    </div>

        {{ comments.count }} Comment{{ comments|pluralize }}
        {% for comment in comments %}
        <blockquote class="blockquote">
        <img style="float:left; clear: left;" class="rounded-circle article-img" height="10" width="10" src="{{ comment.user.profile.profile_pic.url }}"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;"><h6>{{ comment.user.first_name|capfirst }} {{ comment.user.last_name|capfirst }}</h6></a><br>
        <p style="font-size: 8px;">{{ comment.timestamp }}</p>
        <p style="font-size: 14px;" class="mb-3">{{ comment.content }}</p>
        <a  type="button" name="button" class="reply-btn ml-4"><p style="font-size: 13px;"> Reply</p></a>
        {% if request.user == comment.user %}
        <a href="{% url 'posts:delete_comment' comment.id %}" style="font-size: 13px;text-decoration: none; color: #000;" hover="background-color:red">Delete</a></td>
        {% endif %}
        </blockquote>
            {{ comment.reply.count }}
        <div class="replied-comments col-md-5" style="display: none;"> 
            {% for reply in comment.replies.all %} <!--replies is the related name in the model--> 
                <blockquote class="blockquote">
                    <img style="float:left; clear: left;" class="rounded-circle article-img" height="50" width="50" src="{{ reply.user.profile.profile_pic.url }}"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;"><h6>{{ reply.user.first_name|capfirst }} {{ reply.user.last_name|capfirst }}</h6></a><br>
                    <p style="font-size: 13px;" class="mb-3">{{ reply.content }}</p>
                </blockquote>
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="form-group row">
                    <form class="reply-form" method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="{{ comment.id }}">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea name="content" cols="60" rows="2" maxlength="1000" required="" id="id_content"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn-sm btn-outline-light" style="color: black;">
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

PS. The comment is correctly showing in the detail view, but in homepage its showing all the comments of all posts in every posts.

Comment: Can you update your question to show your models.py and remove detail view?

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: Can you also show Post snippet that you use in your homepage?

Comment: Sure..I have done that too. it might be a little mess.

Comment: sorry for delay `posts/comment_section.html` what file is this?

Comment: That's ok. Thats the comment snippet which i have added to the question above. You can find that above models.

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the following changes,

**views.py**

```
 ...
comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=posts_list.first()) # Delete this line 
    context = {
            'page':page,
            'posts':posts,
            'tag':tag,
            'actions':actions,
            'comments': comments, # Delete this too
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/users/myhome.html', context)
```

Change `posts/comment_section.html` too,

```
<!-- Comment showing section -->
<div class="main-comment-section">
    <div class="container-fluid mt-2">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <!-- Comment Form -->
            <form class="comment-form" method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="content" cols="60" rows="2" maxlength="1000" required="" id="id_content"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn-sm btn-outline-light" style="color: black;">Comment</button>
            </form>
            <!-- Comment Form end -->
        </div>
    </div>

        {% if not post.comment_set.all %}
             No comments to display.
        {% endif %}

        {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
        <blockquote class="blockquote">
        <img style="float:left; clear: left;" class="rounded-circle article-img" height="10" width="10" src="{{ comment.user.profile.profile_pic.url }}"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;"><h6>{{ comment.user.first_name|capfirst }} {{ comment.user.last_name|capfirst }}</h6></a><br>
        <p style="font-size: 8px;">{{ comment.timestamp }}</p>
        <p style="font-size: 14px;" class="mb-3">{{ comment.content }}</p>
        <a  type="button" name="button" class="reply-btn ml-4"><p style="font-size: 13px;"> Reply</p></a>
        {% if request.user == comment.user %}
        <a href="{% url 'posts:delete_comment' comment.id %}" style="font-size: 13px;text-decoration: none; color: #000;" hover="background-color:red">Delete</a></td>
        {% endif %}
        </blockquote>
            {{ comment.reply.count }}
        <div class="replied-comments col-md-5" style="display: none;"> 
            {% for reply in comment.replies.all %} <!--replies is the related name in the model--> 
                <blockquote class="blockquote">
                    <img style="float:left; clear: left;" class="rounded-circle article-img" height="50" width="50" src="{{ reply.user.profile.profile_pic.url }}"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;"><h6>{{ reply.user.first_name|capfirst }} {{ reply.user.last_name|capfirst }}</h6></a><br>
                    <p style="font-size: 13px;" class="mb-3">{{ reply.content }}</p>
                </blockquote>
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="form-group row">
                    <form class="reply-form" method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="{{ comment.id }}">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea name="content" cols="60" rows="2" maxlength="1000" required="" id="id_content"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn-sm btn-outline-light" style="color: black;">
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```